# How to map all available fields in two class (without inherience)

Tags: java, mapping

Assume that I have two class A and B,

class A has many, many fields.
class B has some fields, all fields occurs in class A.

Is it possible to automatically map available fields from object A to object B?

@edit

```
class A {
    private int field1;
    private int field2;
    private int field3;
    private int field4;
    private int field5;
    private int field6;
    private int field7;

    // getters, setters
}

class B {
    private int field2;
    private int field6;

    // getters, setters
}
```

when I object of A and B, I want to get fields from A and put to B. But I don't want to use getters/setters, but automatically

Comment: Please provide an example code snippet. Also, what do you mean by automatically mapping?

Comment: Yes, that is possible, e.g. via Reflection. But what do you actually want to achieve, why do you want to map, how many fields are there, are they publicly accessible, etc?

Comment: Don't you just want to inherit or am i misunderstanding this? => https://javascript.info/class-inheritance

Comment: You can use ObjectMapper library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use reflection:

```
A a = new A();
B b = new B();

a.field1 = 1;
a.field2 = 3;

for (Field aField : a.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
    try {
        Field bCounterpart = b.getClass().getDeclaredField(aField.getName());
        if (bCounterpart.getType().equals(aField.getType())) { // Doesn't work well with autoboxing etc. The types have to explictly match
            bCounterpart.setAccessible(true); // Only for private fields
            aField.setAccessible(true); // Only for private fields
            bCounterpart.set(b, aField.get(a));
        }
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        // B doesn't have the field
    }
}

System.out.println(b.field2); // 3
System.out.println(b.field6); // 0
```